# Help to understand and verify this question regards Spectral Thereom

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

But I don't how to verify that it is an orthonormal basis, because their inner product doesn't equal to 0

Comment: Yes, it does. Check the definition of the canonical inner product over the complex field.

Comment: I've verify that it's an orthonormal basis. But I still have no idea, why they're also  eigenvectors of T

Comment: Check that $T v = \lambda v$.

Answer (score 2):

$\langle(i,1),(-i,1) \rangle =i.\overline{(-i)}+1.\overline{(1)}=i.i+1=0$. Note that inner product in $\mathbb{C^2}$ has the form $\langle(x,y),(z,w) \rangle= x\overline z+y \overline w$.

So they are orthogonal.

Comment: How do I proceed to verify that they are basis and consisting of eigenvectors of T that with respect to this basis ? I'm not sure if I understand the question. Does it mean that they also are eigenvector of T ?

Comment: If you don't mind. Could u start to prove this question by from beginning ? From the very top: normal operator T  part ?

Comment: @Hobbit6094: show that $T^*T=TT^*$. These two vectors are linearly ind. as they are orthogonal. They form eigenvectors of $T$- show this from definition of eigenvectors.